# cv_bridge and opencv3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My system is ubuntu14.04, and I am using ros jade and opencv3.2. But my cv_bridge is based on libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.
So when I need to use cv_bridge, I will meet such warning as below:
/`usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_highgui.so.2.4, needed by /opt/ros/jade/lib/libcv_bridge.so, may conflict with libopencv_highgui.so.3.2`
what should i do to make cv_bridge depend on libopencv_highgui.so.3.2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262274/cv_bridge-and-opencv3/) by [ToughMind](https://answers.ros.org/users/30487/toughmind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add cv-bridge package into your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [waschbaer](https://answers.ros.org/users/30263/waschbaer/) with karma: 18 on 2017-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0